# How do I add a link to an image that already got a rollover script?

Tags: javascript, html, rollover

so this is my current script but i cant seem to get it right with the link please help me and add a link (to a sub-page) when i click the image that is active when i hover over it. Do I need to insert the new line before the last `</a>`?

```
<a href="URL ADDRESS">
    <img
        src="test.com/test1.png";
        onmouseover="this.src='test.com/test2.png'"; 
        onmouseout="this.src='test.com/test1'"; />
</a>
```

I have tried several ways but I am really new at this and I cant figure it out.

Comment: <a href="URL ADDRESS"><img src="http://test.com/test1.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://test.com/test2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://test.com/test1'" /></a>

Comment: You should include all relevant code as part of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please use the edit button to add more details instead of writing them into the comments.

Comment: You have semi-colons in there that should be inside the quotes. And remove the semi colon after the src attribute.

Comment: @ManoDestra the semicolon are not correct thats true, but they should not have an effect here.

Comment: Works fine on my browser, but we can't guarantee that necessarily. It should be written correctly to prevent unforeseen issues.

Comment: @Julius Have the answers below corrected the issue for you? If not, then you shall have to be cleared as to what your requirements are and where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, the semicolons are unnecessary and misplaced !

```
<a href="URL ADDRESS">
<img src="test.com/test1.png"
    onmouseover="this.src='test.com/test2.png'"
    onmouseout="this.src='test.com/test1'"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead. Your semi-colons are only relevant in the script handlers. You had them outside the attributes which would be invalid HTML. And the one after src was incorrect.

```
<a href="URL ADDRESS">
    <img
        src="test.com/test1.png"
        onmouseover="this.src='test.com/test2.png';" 
        onmouseout="this.src='test.com/test1';" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. 
Ps.
I used JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
      $(this).attr('src','test.com/test2.png');
      $(this).parent('a').attr('href','link when mouse enter the img');
    },function(){
      $(this).attr('src','test.com/test1');
      $(this).parent('a').attr('href','link when mouse leave the img');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="URL ADDRESS">
    <img
        src="test.com/test1.png";
        onmouseover="this.src='test.com/test2.png'"; 
        onmouseout="this.src='test.com/test1'"; />
</a>
```